# C++ external assembly: where is error in my code?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

main.cpp

```
// Calls the external LongRandom function, written in

// assembly language, that returns an unsigned 32-bit

// random integer. Compile in the Large memory model.

// Procedure called LongRandomArray that fills an array with 32-bit unsigned 

// random integers

#include <iostream.h>

#include <conio.h>

extern "C" {

          unsigned long LongRandom();

          void LongRandomArray(unsigned long * buffer, unsigned count);

           }

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;

int main()

{

  // Allocate array storage and fill with 32-bit

  // unsigned random integers.

  unsigned long * rArray = new unsigned long[ARRAY_SIZE];

  LongRandomArray(rArray,ARRAY_SIZE);

  for(unsigned i = 0; i < 20; i++)

  {

    cout << rArray[i] << ',';

  }

  cout << endl;

  getch();

  return 0;

}
```

`LongRandom` & `LongRandomArray` procedure module      (longrand.asm)

```
.model large

.386

Public _LongRandom

Public _LongRandomArray

.data

seed  dd 12345678h

; Return an unsigned pseudo-random 32-bit integer

; in DX:AX,in the range 0 - FFFFFFFFh.

.code

_LongRandom  proc far, C 

      mov   eax, 214013

      mul  seed

      xor   edx,edx

      add   eax, 2531011

      mov   seed, eax    ; save the seed for the next call

      shld  edx,eax,16   ; copy upper 16 bits of EAX to DX

      ret

_LongRandom  endp

_LongRandomArray  proc far, C 

ARG bufferPtr:DWORD, count:WORD

; fill random array

      mov edi,bufferPtr

      mov cx, count

L1:

     call _LongRandom

     mov word ptr [edi],dx

     add edi,2

     mov word ptr [edi],ax

     add edi,2   

     loop L1

     ret

_LongRandomArray  endp

end
```

Comment: What's happening there ? We're not compilers, what's the output ? The expected output ? What's wrong there ?

Comment: Exactly, please tell us what happens and what you expected would happen.

Comment: @DimitriMockelyn, "We're not compilers" is cool!

Comment: Also this is not inline assembly, it's just plain x86 assembler code.

Comment: Where exactly do you exit the `L1` loop?

Comment: @molbdnilo the `loop` instruction exits when `ecx` reaches zero. Of course OP should load `ecx` not `cx` for that, not to mention follow calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

This code is based on on an 16-bit example for MS-DOS from Kip Irvine's assembly book (6th ed.) and explicitely written for Borland C++ 5.01 and TASM 4.0 (see chapter 13.4 "Linking to C/C++ in Real-Address Mode").

Pointers in 16-bit-mode consist of a segment and an offset, usually written as `segment:offset`. This is **not** the real memory address which will calculated by the processor. You can **not** load `segment:offset` in a 32-bit-register (`EDI`) and store a value to the memory. So

```
...
mov edi,bufferPtr
...
mov word ptr [edi],dx
...
```

is **wrong**. You have to load the segment part of the pointer in a segment register e.g. `ES`, the offset part in a appropriate general 16-bit register eg. `DI` and to possibly use a segment override:

```
...
push es
les di,bufferPtr         ; bufferPtr => ES:DI
...
mov word ptr es:[di],dx
...
pop es
...
```

The `ARG` replaces the name of the variable with the appropriate `[bp+x]` operand. Therefor you need a prologue (and an epilogue). TASM inserts the right instruction, if the `PROC` header is well written what is not the case here. Take a look at following working function:

```
_LongRandomArray PROC C FAR
ARG bufferPtr:DWORD, count:WORD
    push es
    les di,bufferPtr
    mov cx, count
L1:
    call _LongRandom
    mov word ptr es:[di],dx
    add di,2
    mov word ptr es:[di],ax
    add di,2
    loop L1
    pop es
    ret
_LongRandomArray ENDP
```

Compile your code with BCC (**not** BCC32):

```
BCC -ml main.cpp longrand.asm
```